# Load beans/controller from external jar in spring boot without changing config class

Tags: spring-boot

I want to load a bean from a external jar into spring boot project. But I don't want to make changes to existing spring boot config file. I want same behavior like actuator. Just add dependency and bean or endpoint will be available in spring boot